# Ищу похожее на pageX свойство

Tags: javascript, html, веб-программирование, drag-n-drop

Делаю Drag and Drop на сайте. У меня расчитывается положение и перемещение элемента с помощью этих строчек:

```
// запомним, что элемент нажат на текущих координатах pageX/pageY
      dragObject.downX = e.pageX;
      dragObject.downY = e.pageY;
// создать вспомогательные свойства shiftX/shiftY
      var coords = getCoords(dragObject.avatar);
      dragObject.shiftX = dragObject.downX - coords.left;
      dragObject.shiftY = dragObject.downY - coords.top;

// отобразить перенос объекта при каждом движении мыши
      dragObject.avatar.style.left = e.pageX - dragObject.shiftX + 'px';
      dragObject.avatar.style.top = e.pageY - dragObject.shiftY + 'px';

function getCoords(elem){
      top: box.top + pageYOffset,
      left: box.left + pageXOffset
}
```

Но так как relative для этого элемента менее широкий и ниже, чем вся страница, то отображение происходит некорректно. И если высота фиксированая и можно просто вычесть разницу, то ширина не фиксирована.

Вопрос: Есть ли какое-то свойство идентичное pageX/Y, которое будет считать координаты относительно relative? Или есть другой способ реализовать это корректно?

Answer (score 0):

используйте свойство clientX и clientY вместо pageX и pageY. Эти свойства возвращают координаты мыши относительно верхнего левого угла видимой области браузера, то есть вашей видимой области содержащей элемент.

```
dragObject.downX = e.clientX;
dragObject.downY = e.clientY;

var coords = getCoords(dragObject.avatar);
dragObject.shiftX = dragObject.downX - coords.left;
dragObject.shiftY = dragObject.downY - coords.top;

dragObject.avatar.style.left = e.clientX - dragObject.shiftX + 'px';
dragObject.avatar.style.top = e.clientY - dragObject.shiftY + 'px';
```

Comment: Не сработало. Может это из-за строчек, которые я не добавил в вопрос. (Уже добавил)

Comment: Я же написал, что мне не нужно отслеживать элемент по всему окну, а нужно только во вложеном div.content    Вот у меня есть body условно 2000px и div.content 1600px и так как у меня div.content - relative и мой элемент находится в нём, то перемещение относительно всего окна будет отображаться некорректно так как relative выступает элемент, у которого ширина меньше

Comment: странно(( нужно разбираться. значит где то есть конфликты